# Why only generic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following situation:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two projective irreducible varieties with the same dimension and $f:X\to Y$ a surjective morphism between them. Then $f$ is generically finite.

Why do we have only generic finiteness?

I mean, if I look at a fibre which is not generic, what can be wrong? Is it only a technical issue or I am losing something? For example, is $f$ quasi-finite (i.e. every fibre is a finite set of points)?

Thank you very much!

P.S.: I want to prove the statement above and I am trying to understand why my intuition is wrong.

Comment: No, $f$ need not be quasi-finite. The basic counterexample is blowing up a point in $Y$. (By the way, quasi-finite maps between projective varieties are finite.)

Comment: @Nefertiti, thank you for the counter-example. I see the necessity to work generically. For the bracket remark: do you need a finite-type assumption there?

Comment: Every projective variety is finite type over the base field.

Comment: @Nefertiti, I mean that I need $f$ to be of finite-type?

Comment: Basically the proof is that the dimension of $X$ equals the sum of the dimension of $Y$ and the dimension of the generic fibre. You find this in Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra in chapter 13. I think the statement you need is 13.5

Comment: If $X$ is finite type over $k$, and $X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism over $k$, then $X$ is certainly of finite type over $Y$. (Check the definitions.) So any morphism between projective varieties is also of finite type. If I may offer an unsolicited opinion: it is a very good idea, when learning these general properties of schemes and morphisms, whether they are automatically true for projective varieties, quasi-projective varieties, etc.

Comment: Thank you both. I've got it.